# classes and methods in java

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans

I was just goofing around with java when i thought of trying to get my work done not from a method but from a class. Check out what I did.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class foolingAround{
    public static void main(String ARG[]) {
        createMyInterface();
    }

    private static void createMyInterface(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame from Swing but not from other class");
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        new createAnotherInterface();
    }

}

class createAnotherInterface{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        giveMe();
    }

    static JFrame giveMe(){
        JFrame p = new JFrame("Frame from Swing and from another class");
        p.setSize(100,100);
        p.setVisible(true);
        return p;
    }
}
```

It compiled without showing any error but the frame from `class createAnotherInterface` did not show up. Why? When do i make different classes and not methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not show up"? And this issue occurs when you run *which* of the two programs, seeing as both have `main` methods?

Comment: just calling  new createAnotherInterface(); doesn't mean it will invoke main methods and it doesn't make sense to name it as static main method unless that class is main method (it just adds more confusion).

Comment: What do you mean "not from a method? There isn't a single line of code outside of a method in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just creating a new Object for createAnotherInterface class and by default it calls its default constructor and in that default constructor there is no call to giveMe() method.

I am not sure if i am right or wrong but i ask you to create a constructor in "createAnotherInterface" class and call the "giveMe()" method in the constuctor. i hope that will solve your problem.

or atleast call

```
new createAnotherInterface().giveMe();
```

in your createMyInterface() class

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating the second class will not call its "main" method - you have to explicitly call the `giveMe()` method from the first class:

```
private static void createMyInterface(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame from Swing but not from other class");
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        new createAnotherInterface().giveMe();
    }
```

The "main" function is called "entry point" and it is the function the JVM jumps to when "launching" a java application. As there can be multiple main in different classes, that's why you have to specify "which class" when launching from the command line

Comment: `giveMe()` is static, so it should be called statically: `createAnotherInterface.giveMe()`.

Answer (score 1):

With `new createAnotherInterface();` you are creating a new object only, not launching the `giveMe()` or `main`.

There are multiple ways you can "foolAround" to solve your issue, probably the easiest is to change:

`new createAnotherInterface();`

into

`createAnotherInterface.giveMe();`

Also, note that `createAnotherInterface` is not an interface and you should follow [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) once the "foolingAround" phase is done.

Answer (score 1):

Your createAnotherInterface class shouldn't have a main method, and if it does, it isn't getting called.  It should have a constructor, or you should use your reference to your instance of that class to call the giveMe() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 new createAnotherInterface();
```

Will only call the `createAnotherInterface`'s default constructor.

You have to call `giveMe()` explicitly from your `foolingAround` class.

```
private static void createMyInterface(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame from Swing but not from other class");
    f.setSize(100,100);
    f.setVisible(true);
    createAnotherInterface.giveMe();
}
```

or write the constructor for your CreateAnotherInterface.

```
    class createAnotherInterface{
    public createAnotherInterface(){
    giveMe();
    }
    public class FoolingAround {
    private static void createMyInterface(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame from Swing but not from other class");
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        new createAnotherInterface();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have copied your codes and tested it. The filename is `createAnotherInterface.java`.

It works and the `JFrame` comes out.

Answer (score 0):

You have named the method `giveMe`, consider to refactoring to constructor `createAnotherInterface` or just create a constructor that initiate that method.